# DRF Serializer readable - writeable non-model field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

On a project with Django / DRF; I have the following model structure:

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Company(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    .
    .
```

And following serializer structure for Company model:

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    city_name = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    .
    .

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('city_name',)

    def create(self, validated_data):

        # Get city
        city_name = validated_data.pop('city_name')
        try: 
            city = City.objects.get(name__iexact=city_name)
        except City.DoesNotExist:
            city = City.objects.create(name=city_name.title())

        company = Company.objects.create(city=city, **validated_data)

        return company
```

While creating a company through the serializer, user provides a city_name, I create a new city with that name if not exists or use an existing entry if exists. In this structure, I want to be able to return city_name field while returning companies. It is not a field on the model, so I could use SerializerMethodField normally, but I also want this field to be writable as well. Do I have any options here?

Comment: show you create method, please

Comment: @BearBrown updated the question with create method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think, your solution is simple to add [source](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) and remove `write_only`:

```
city_name = serializers.CharField(source='city.name')
```

After changing to this approach, you can get city name in create or update methods as follows:

```
city_data = validated_data.pop('city')
city_name = city_data.get('name')
```

Comment: yup, that did it. In the create method, I needed to get city name as validated_data.get('city')['name']

Comment: @OzgurAkcali may be about get city name i'm not sure, but if so, please, correct my answer for other who will search such solution

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to create two serializer

```
class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ('name')

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city = CitySerializer(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('city',)

    def create(self, validated_data):

        # Get city
        city = validated_data.pop('city')
        try:
            city = City.objects.get(name__iexact=city)
        except City.DoesNotExist:
            city = City.objects.create(name=city.title())

        company = Company.objects.create(city=city, **validated_data)

        return company
```